# Check if a file includes some content

Tags: vim

Thanks to a previous answer, I can test if a file exists using

```
if !empty(glob("filename"))
  ...
endif
```

I now want to check if the file `filename` contains text `text`.

If possible, I want to do this using native vimscript only, not calling system's grep etc commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if filereadable("filename") && match(readfile("filename"),"text")
   ...
endif
```

See `:help function-list` for a high-level overview of vimscript functions.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I had to add `!= -1`

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
if match(readfile(expand("%:p")),"pattern")!=-1
   # content
endif
```

to check if a file contains a pattern in vimscript