# How do I check if a file is empty using vimscript?

Tags: vim

I have written my own linter in vimscript which lints a file using an external linting tool, and then reads the output into the quickfix window. I want to echo a message if there were no errors, but how can I check if that file is empty to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a file includes some content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822833/check-if-a-file-includes-some-content)

Comment: Oh, I slightly misinterpreted the title of the other question. It may still be useful.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have just tried `if match(readfile(g:linterErrFile),".") == -1` but that does not seem to work

Comment: Why do you write the output of the linter to some file to begin with? Can't you simply run it as a filter?

Comment: Hi @romainl I write it to a file because I run it via a term `job_start` command so I can run it asynchronously in the background. I get this job to output to a temporary file, and then in my callback I check if the file is readable, and if it is then I use `cfile` to read it into the quickfix window.

Comment: `if getfsize("filename") < 1` or something like that.

Comment: @Matt works perfectly, surprised I didn't find that using `helpgrep`. Thanks for that. I think you might need to elaborate on your answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually there's no need to check if temporary file is `filereadable()`. So only this should be enough:

```
if getfsize(tempname) < 1
    throw "cannot read temporary file"
endif
```